# How to list number of apps installed or running only on the sd card in Android?

Tags: android, adb, android-sdcard

Wanted to know, how do we list all the apps running or installed only on the sd card in android device?
is there any adb command for it?
please let me know, if anybody knows.

thank you.

Answer (score -1):

adb shell pm list packages

That should do it.

Comment: well ,this would list all the apps in the device, I just want only the apps on the sd card